# Unable to update Google Chrome to version 76 in macOS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I tried to update by going to the top right corner in the Chrome window to the three dots and going to Help/About Google Chrome and this error shows up.

[image]

Comment: Did you do any searching on the error code?

Comment: You will most likely need to manually install the latest Chrome.